# gmp_printf() - print in hexadecimal / base16

Tags: c, hex, printf, gmp

I am trying to print in hexadecimal using gmp_printf() , but for somereason it doesn't work / works strangely.

```
mpz_t B; //number of bytes
mpz_set_str(B,argv[2],0);
gmp_printf("%Zd",B);
```

Works fine.

tried to change it to:

```
gmp_printf("%#0xZd",B);
```

But using this I get different outputs for the same input:

```
input: 0x397a52dccd55d39823964ae25
output1: 0xa8392f80Zd
output2: 0xa1eca3b0Zd
desired output: 0x397a52dccd55d39823964ae25
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `gmp_printf("%#Zx\n",B);`. Please **never** post random lines like this, only complete programs (with `#include <gmp.h>`, with `mpz_init(B)`, etc).